# Why does sending a trapped signal cause `read` to return in POSIX shell but not in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, read

I was trying to write a shell script that idly waits for a signal in the background. Since the script doesn't take user input I thought of using `read` to block the script indefinitely while waiting.

In bash the following code seems to work as expected, outputing "signal" every time it receives a SIGUSR1:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo signal" SIGUSR1
read
```

```
$ ./test
signal
signal
...
```

However if I run with `#!/bin/sh` or BusyBox ash, sending SIGUSR1 also causes the program to terminate:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
trap "echo signal" SIGUSR1
read
```

```
$ ./test
signal
$
```

Shouldn't `read` only return after reading EOF or IFS from standard input? In this case that didn't happen, so what caused its return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dash and BusyBox comply with the POSIX specification by making the signal quit `read` immediately. Bash doesn't, unless invoked in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#index-POSIX-Mode). The section on [signals](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11) states

> When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a foreground command, the trap associated with that signal shall not be executed until after the foreground command has completed.

`read` is not a [special built-in](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), so it is a “utility executing as a foreground command”, even if it happens to run inside the same process. This rules out the bash behavior of running the trap and continuing the execution of `read`.

The section on the [execution environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) clarifies how signals work when running a utility (once again, including non-special built-ins):

> If the utility is a shell script, traps caught by the shell shall be set to the default values and traps ignored by the shell shall be set to be ignored by the utility; if the utility is not a shell script, the trap actions (default or ignore) shall be mapped into the appropriate signal handling actions for the utility

A built-in is not a shell script, but arguably it's still running as part of a shell that's executing a script, so the first clause could apply. But neither behaviors allow the utility to run the parent's trap. The only possible behaviors are for `read` to ignore the signal, block it, or let it return immediately. The description of [`read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) doesn't mention signals, so it isn't allowed to change the mask of a standard signal, which rules out ignoring. `read` could arguably block the signal until it finishes (programs may temporarily block signals for internal purposes) — but this would conflict with the expectation that `read` does not block a SIGINT while it's waiting for input (with Occam's razor saying that it wouldn't make sense to only have this behavior for SIGINT). So having `read` do nothing upon SIGUSR1 (which is how mksh behaves) might be technically compliant, but I don't find this to be reasonable behavior.

Dash and BusyBox aren't fully POSIX-compliant. Both (as of the versions in Ubuntu 22.04) set `$?` to 1 if `read` is interrupted by a signal, which contradicts the requirement on [exit status](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02).

> The exit status of a command that terminated because it received a signal shall be reported as greater than 128.

(In practice that's 128 + signal value, except ATT ksh where it's 256 + signal value.)